# ddos protection for dedicated server

Tags: ddos

Whats the best way to protect a linux root server from a ddos attack?
I just want to inform myself about the issue. I'm wondering I haven't found a good solution.
anybody has one?
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no effective way to "protect" your server from a DDoS.  Your best option is to contact your upstream provider and ask for their assistance in mitigating the attack before it reaches your gateway.

Answer (score 1):

[Prolexic](http://www.prolexic.com/) is a Denial of Service (DoS) mitigation service that I've had pleasant experience with but it isn't low cost.

Otherwise, it's going to be circumstantial.  Without huge pipes, expensive networking equipment, and strong technical knowledge these situations are difficult to deal with.  Some ISPs are more helpful than others.

Answer (score 0):

The most affordable way would be to use a reverse proxy such as Staminus or Blacklotus. They would filter out the traffic for you and then send only the clean traffic to your server.